# Virtualbox: Fail to mount folder on Ubuntu16.04

Tags: mount, virtualbox

My host: Ubuntu16.04
My guest: Ubuntu16.04
Virtualbox: 5.1.24
And I want to mount a shared file folder:

```
httpd@vm:~$ sudo modprobe vboxsf
httpd@vm:~$ dmesg | grep vboxsf
[  370.430604] vboxsf: Successfully loaded version 5.0.18_Ubuntu (interface 0x00010004)

httpd@vm:~$ sudo mount -t vboxsf ShareFolder /mnt/shareFolder/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on ShareFolder,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
httpd@vm:~$ dmesg | tail
[    9.630749] fbcon: vboxdrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    9.638295] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 100x37
[    9.639474] vboxvideo 0000:00:02.0: fb0: vboxdrmfb frame buffer device
[    9.645298] [drm] Initialized vboxvideo 1.0.0 20130823 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[   11.383860] e1000: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
[   11.850899] floppy0: no floppy controllers found
[   11.850934] work still pending
[  370.430604] vboxsf: Successfully loaded version 5.0.18_Ubuntu (interface 0x00010004)
[  372.819494] sf_read_super_aux err=-22
[ 1108.433531] sf_read_super_aux err=-22
```

I found most answers online fixed this problem by fixing a bad symlink of `/sbin/mount.vboxsf`, but under my `/sbin/` folder, this is no `mount.vboxsf` file.

```
httpd@vm:~$ ls /sbin/ | grep mount*
mount.fuse
mount.lowntfs-3g
mount.ntfs
mount.ntfs-3g
mount.vmhgfs
```

Answer (score 0):

Your guest user needs to be in the `vboxsf` group.

```
sudo adduser your_username vboxsf
```

Then logout/login, or reboot the guest OS.

Assuming that you've properly setup a shared folder in the prefs, open a Files (Nautilus) window and you'll find the shared folder in the left pane. Just single-click on it to open it.